# GPT2 on Hugging face(pytorch transformers) RuntimeError: grad can be implicitly created only for scalar outputs

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am trying to fine-tune gpt2 with a custom dataset of mine. I created a basic example with the documentation from hugging-face transformers. I receive the mentioned error. I know what it means: (basically it is calling backward on a non-scalar tensor) but since I almost use only API calls, I have no idea how to fix this issue. Any suggestions?

```
from pathlib import Path
from absl import flags, app
import IPython
import torch
from transformers import GPT2LMHeadModel, Trainer,  TrainingArguments
from data_reader import GetDataAsPython

# this is my custom data, but i get the same error for the basic case below
# data = GetDataAsPython('data.json')
# data = [data_point.GetText2Text() for data_point in data]
# print("Number of data samples is", len(data))

data = ["this is a trial text", "this is another trial text"]

train_texts = data

from transformers import GPT2Tokenizer
tokenizer = GPT2Tokenizer.from_pretrained('gpt2')

special_tokens_dict = {'pad_token': '<PAD>'}
num_added_toks = tokenizer.add_special_tokens(special_tokens_dict)
train_encodigs = tokenizer(train_texts, truncation=True, padding=True)


class BugFixDataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, encodings):
        self.encodings = encodings
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        item = {key: torch.tensor(val[index]) for key, val in self.encodings.items()}
        return item

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.encodings['input_ids'])

train_dataset = BugFixDataset(train_encodigs)

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir='./results',          
    num_train_epochs=3,              
    per_device_train_batch_size=1,  
    per_device_eval_batch_size=1,   
    warmup_steps=500,                
    weight_decay=0.01,               
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=10,
)

model = GPT2LMHeadModel.from_pretrained('gpt2', return_dict=True)
model.resize_token_embeddings(len(tokenizer))

trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
)

trainer.train()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. The problem was that the data samples did not contain a target output. Even tough gpt is self-supervised, this has to be explicitly told to the model.

you have to add the line:

```
item['labels'] = torch.tensor(self.encodings['input_ids'][index])
```

to the **getitem** function of the Dataset class and then it runs okay!

Comment: Is this index not supposed to be the index into your dataset rather than an index into your encoding vector?

Comment: yes the index is with respect to the dataset. In my case, self.encodings[input_ids] is a list of list so it contains encoding vectors in 2D matrix so to say. Thats why one I apply the index, I actually get an encoding vector corresponding to the dataset.

Comment: I had to go do it myself and then I realize what you meant. This is great!